# SQL convert foreign key table into a specific value from other table

Tags: sql

I want to convert all the foreign key values in my relations table into their names from my `familyMember` table. I've tried to convert two columns by using this but did not work.

```
SELECT familyMember.name AS "Person", familyMember.name AS "Father Name"
FROM familyMember, relations
WHERE familyMember.id = relations.id  
  AND familyMember.id = relations.father
```

My tables:

[image: familyMember]

[image: relations]

Im doing this for a java project that i'm doing, How do I do this?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**almost 30 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to join familyMember to relations twice

```
SELECT *
FROM
  relations r
  INNER JOIN familyMember c ON r.child = c.id
  INNER JOIN familyMember f ON r.father = f.id
```

The details of the child are given by the c.* table. The details of the father are given by the f.* table. Always remember that you can join the same table multiple times and in cases like these you must because there is no single row of `familyMember` that is simultaneously a parent and a child, so you can't say "relations join familymember on child = x and father = x" - you'll get no rows (unless there is an error in the relations table data and someone has been listed as a parent of themselves)

When joining a table multiple times, always give them a good alias. Here I use `f` for father and `c` for child. `fm1` and `fm2` would be an example of bad aliases to use